# In-ovo chick sexing vs. unemployment

Tags: unemployment, automation, food

As they report in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_sexing), daily 7 million male chicks are killed for economic reasons.

What I did not know is that obviously the actual separation, *sexing* is done manually?

> Instrument or machine sexing of chickens has almost disappeared.

Does this mean, the German upcoming law for in-ovo sexing, in case it will happen automatically which appears realistic, effectively add to unemployment? Is there any estimation how many jobs are bound here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technology would be implemented on a large scale regardless of any countries law mandating it's use. Firms would save a lot of resources if they could get rid of eggs at the 4-20 day mark rather than the 22-25 day mark as this is when they start consuming food. As per unemployment it seems these numbers wont be large. A back of the envelope calculation from snippets off google:

62 million chicken births per day
chicken sexers can do 5000-8000 in a day
Realistically >15000 jobs world-wide